# Python Packages not recognized by iPython

Tags: python, macos, ipython

I have been using python 3 on OS X for ~6 months now and have recently been turned onto iPython.  I have installed some python packages using the pip install tool as follows:

```
python3.6 -m pip install matplotlib
```

I installed iPython (running python3.6) using the pip install tool as well, however, once in iPython, the packages previously installed are not recognized.  I'm sure there is a way to 'point' iPython to the locations of the packages, I just don't know what it is.  I know this is a basic question, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you `import sys; print sys.path` under both iPython and the normal REPL and show us the differences?

Comment: What you _should_ see is that IPython has the exact same list as normal Python, plus a couple extra directories at the end (system-wide and per-user `IPython/extensions` directories). If you see that your system-wide site-packages directory (something like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-download`, but the first part of them may be different for Homebrew or Anaconda) aren't showing up in IPython, that's the issue to fix.

Comment: Also: Have you been using virtual environments at all?

Comment: It appears that iPython was initially installed alongside miniconda, but I was installing packages to my systems version of python, not the miniconda library.  Thus when I tried to load packages in iPython they couldn't be found.  Uninstalling that version of iPython and re-installing without miniconda solved the problem.  I have not been working in virtual environments yet, but as I get more involved in the bioinformatics aspect of my project I will need to.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible for this to occur when you have multiple versions of Python on your system.

**The cause:**

The setup for IPython is somewhat a mess (as is Python packaging in general), and you may not be interested in the details of how it gets into a screwed up state so I'll keep it brief: the "ipython" command is really just a plain old python script with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).  It's created by the installer `console_scripts`.

`pip` monkeypatches `setuptools` which monkeypatches `distutils` which munges the shebang at install time: [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/300dd552b15825abfe0e367ac14cec4c3e050dbc/Lib/distutils/command/build_scripts.py#L107).

**The solution:**

Find which Python interpreter is bound to your console script, something like this:

```
$ head -1 $(which ipython)
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Use that interpreter to uninstall IPython, something like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 -m pip uninstall ipython
```

Re-install IPython for the interpreter you want, something like this:

```
$ python3.6 -m pip install ipython
```

**Bonus:** If you want to use ipython with both a system level Python 2 interpreter and a system level Python 3 interpreter, consider setting up aliases in your bashrc or similar:

```
alias ipython2="python2 /path/to/ipython"
alias ipython3="python3 /path/to/ipython"
```

You can do similar with `pip2` and `pip3`.  Note that ipython has dropped support for Python 2 in v6.0, but it is quite fine to have both `~=5.6` installed in Python 2's site-packages and latest installed in Python 3's site-packages.